# How to receve a file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a chat app.

The frontend send a message with a file to node server.

The message arrives in node server as an object:

```
{
  author: 'me',
  type: 'file',
  data: {
    file: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 
00 00 ff db 00 84 00 06 06 06 06 07 06 07 08 08 07 0a 0b 0a 0b 0a 0f 0e 
0c 0c 0e 0f 16 10 11 10 ... 56636 more bytes>
  },
  id: 164244440029,
  read: false,
  tto: '2'
}
```

I´d like to recover the file:

1. If the type is an image, I'd like to get the filename,size, mime....  and create a base64 image to send  to frontend. The front end will show it in a html img element
2. otherwise, send as original

I´d like some tip about what I need to do.

Comment: Get the sender to send you a mime-type. Identifying a file from its contents is not a trivial task - check the UNIX tool `file`

Comment: @mmomtchev Ok, Thanks. I can send the mimetype from front. How about node read the buffer, size ....?

Comment: the size is simply `data.file.length`? what is that you cannot do?

Comment: Does the buffer contains only the the raw bytes from file, or it has others info such as 'lastModified, name, .... '?

Comment: Depends on the one sending it - but generally when one uses a `Buffer` it is to send only the raw contents